# Enabling Playframework response gzip compression in the reverse proxy

Tags: gzip, playframework-2.0, lighttpd, reverse-proxy

There has been a lot of discussion about gzipping Play's response (i.e. rendering HTML from a template). Apparently the developers don't care to add it, at least Page Speed reports that the response in 2.0.3 is not compressed and that my app is generating 70% of useless traffic.

I'm using lighttpd as a reverse proxy. `mod_compress` is enabled, for both `"text/html"` and `"text/html; charset=utf8"`. But Play's response is still not compressed.

Is there any way to do this via the reverse proxy?

Comment: It looks like the current development version of the play framework 2.0 supports gzipped requests via Netty: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/375

Comment: Yep but 2.1 seems to be far away and I don't know if Netty caches zipped requests.